# jQuery-UI - Multiple autocomplete fields shared results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I am trying to build a form with multiple autocompleted fields. I am using jQuery-ui 1.8.21 to do the autocomplete via the .autocomplete binding. I have 5 different fields which have autocomplete bound to them, and each send their suggestions to a different div outside of the form, at the end of the page.

the form looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="afield" />
    <input type="text" name="bfield" />
</form>
<div id="a_complete">
</div>
<div id="b_complete">
</div>
```

the jQuery code like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("[name=afield]").autocomplete({
        source: "/data/source/a",
        open: function(event, ui) {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete')
            .removeAttr('style').hide().appendTo('#a_complete').show();
        }
    });
    $("[name=bfield]").autocomplete({
        source: "/data/source/b",
        open: function(event, ui) {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete')
            .removeAttr('style').hide().appendTo('#b_complete').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that when I begin typing in *bfield*, the matched results for *afield* are also displayed in *b_complete* as well as the results for *bfield*.

I have tried setting *cacheLength* to 0 or 1, and use *flushCache()* on different events (*search, open, close, select*) to no success.

This is only a cosmetic issue though as when I click on a result it will update the proper field, and when I walk through the results with the arrow keys they only return the results for the correct field.

Comment: Try to replace `$('ul.ui-autocomplete')` with `$(this)`

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin I think `$(this)` will make a reference to the input

Comment: @Daniel You are correct, using $(this) sent my input flying across the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your `$('ul.ui-autocomplete')` unique as well, with another class definition, or "id", for example, so that it's `$('ul.ui-autocomplete#a')` and `$('ul.ui-autocomplete#b')`

Comment: that makes sense but isn't he doing it already with `appendTo('#b_complete')` and `appendTo('#a_complete')`?

Comment: @Daniel it will strip the a_complete and b_complete of all <ul>s in the DOM. He has to say specifically which DOM object he wants to strip the styles from, or it will do all of them.